# Rouché's theorem proof question

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

I'm currently studying for a re-exam in Complex analysis, and have a question regarding the proof for Rouches theorem. Below is the exact proof, word by word, our professor have presented.

I understand that this proof might be a shortened version, but there is only one question I have.

$\textbf{Question:}$ When we've asked the question if $(f+sg) \circ \gamma)$ crosses 0, how are we able to say that that through approximating $|f(\gamma(t)) + sg(\gamma(t))|$ that is is greater than 0, without knowing anything about the function?

$\textbf{Theorem:}$

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in $G \subset \mathbb{C}$.
$\gamma$ are positively oriented, simple connected, and piecewise smooth function so that $\gamma \sim_{G} 0$ and that $|f(z)| > |g(z)| \forall z \in G$.
Then $Z(f,\gamma) = Z(f+g,\gamma)$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Notice that $(f \circ sg) \circ \gamma$, $s \in [0,1]$ are a homotopy between $f \circ \gamma$ and $(f+g) \circ \gamma $ in $ \mathbb{C}$. (Which is drawn by a picture to make it clearer).

Does $(f+sg) \circ \gamma$ ever cross 0?

$|f(\gamma(t)) + sg(\gamma(t))| \geq |f(\gamma(t))| - s|g(\gamma(t))| \geq |f(\gamma(t))| - |g(\gamma(t))| > 0$

$\Rightarrow$ never crosses 0!
$ \Rightarrow f \circ \gamma \sim_{\mathbb{C}/0} (f+g) \circ \gamma$.

Using argument principle with winding numbers we get that $Z(f,$ int$(\gamma)$ = $Z(f+g,$ int$(\gamma)$

Comment: Exactly what point of the argument is unclear to you?  There is a chain of inequalities, for instance:  is all of that believable?

Comment: I understand each step in the equality, but not why it would be greater than 0. Will it be greater than 0 because that's how we defined $f$ and $g$? And that's what's needed to make the theorem work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The penultimate line claims that $|f(\gamma(t))|- |g(\gamma(t))| >0.$  If this were false, then $|f(\gamma(t))| \leq |g(\gamma(t))| $.  However, you've assumed that $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$, so this cannot happen.